# Is there a way to extract predicted values, using which XGBoost calculates the train/eval errors (stored in evals_results)?

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I am looking to gain a better understanding of how my model learns a particular dataset. I wanted to visualize the training and eval phases of learning by plotting the actual training/eval data alongside model predictions for the same.

I got the idea from observing some Matlab code, which allows the user to plot the above mentioned values. Unfortunately I no longer have access to the Matlab code and would like to recreate the same in Python.

Using the code below:

```py
model = xgb.train(params, dtrain,evals=watchlist,evals_result=results,verbose_eval=False)
```

I can get a results dictionary which saves, the training and eval rmse values as shown below:

```
{'eval': {'rmse': [0.557375, 0.504097, 0.449699, 0.404737, 0.364217, 0.327787, 0.295155, 0.266028, 0.235819, 0.212781]}, 'train': {'rmse': [0.405989, 0.370338, 0.337915, 0.308605, 0.281713, 0.257068, 0.234662, 0.214531, 0.195993, 0.179145]}}
```

While the output shows me the rmse values, I was wondering whether there is a way to get the predicted values for both the training as well as eval set, using which these rmse values are calculated.

Comment: Using trained model do the prediction on evaluation dataset which is stored in `watchlist`. Then calculate RMSE using actual label of evaluation dataset and obtained prediction. They should match with RMSE that you have here.

Comment: Thank you! This does seem to work.